# Git new file appears in all branches

Tags: git, merge, branch, commit, rebase

I thought a file created on one branch will not appear in any other branches until I merge or rebase the branch?

**Example:**

I have two branches:

1. master
2. new_contact_page

I checkout the **new_contact_page** branch.

```
$ git checkout new_contact_page
```

Then I create a new file.

```
$ vi contact_page.html
```

Without doing any Git commands, I switch back to my **Master** branch.

```
$ git checkout master
```

Then I see that this contact_page.html file is also in my **Master** branch.

```
$ ls   (contact_page.html shows up in the list!)
```

Shouldn't the file only exist in **new_contact_page** branch?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Git will never touch any files that aren't actually in your repository.  (untracked files)

You need to `git add` and `git commit` the file (into one branch) first.

Comment: So if I `git add` and `git commit` the file in **new_contact_page** it will not exist in the **master** branch correct?

Comment: Ah, the answer is yes. This makes a lot of things make more sense. Thanks Slaks

Comment: @DonnyP: To be more precise, until you do that, it won't exist in _any_ branch – it will just be residue on the local filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

This is where is is important to [understand the index (or staging area)](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/10/git-tip-of-week-understanding-index.html).
As long as you don't stage (git add) files, they remain "untracked" (or "private"), and won't be modified by a "git checkout".

That is different from "unstaged" which references tracked file (previously committed in the local Git repo) with local modifications not yet added to the index.

You can read more in "[You could have invented git (and maybe you already have!)](http://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/you-could-have-invented-git-and-maybe-you-already-have/)"