# Visual Studio 2019 (Community) & Git Branching

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-branch

Hoping someone can shed some light.  I've got a .net 3.5 solution that is tracked via a Git repository.  The solution has ~12 projects within it.

If I create a branch, let's say "feature", checkout this branch add a new item - HTMLFile.html to the web project.  I stop here and switch back to the master branch, and the HTMLFile.html is showing as new in the master branch??

Shouldn't this new item only be present in the feature branch?  Once I go to master, it should not exist in this branch?  Am I missing something?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git new file appears in all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341665/git-new-file-appears-in-all-branches)

Comment: This is purely just a Git question. New files aren't tracked until they get committed into your repo.

Comment: Thank you. This clears it up for me.